# Convert string to objectId in pipelie mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Cómo puedo convertir un objectId a string dentro de un pipeline al crear una colección en mongoose.

Estoy creando una vista db.createCollection(........, pipeline: []), dentro del pipeline tengo una $match, $lookup y un $unwind, quiero que el valor del _id que está dentro de la relación del $lookup convertirlo a un string.

he visto que en mongodb 4.x.x tienen el atributo $toString y $toObject, pero en mongoose cuál sería el correspondiente.

Comment: ¿Podrías traducir el título de tu pregunta al castellano? Es el idioma oficial de [es.so]. Saludos

Comment: Por otro lado, todos los operadores disponibles en el driver de MongoDB para NodeJS están disponibles en Mongoose. No veo cuál sería el problema en usarlos directamente. ¿Lo has intentado? ¿Qué problema o error te da? Saludos